# Swap the order of items in a SQLite database

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, ipad, sqlite

I retrieve an ordered list of items from a table of items in a Sqlite Database. How can I swap the id so the order of two items in the Sqlite database table?.

Comment: What did you end up going with?  Did a range or links work for you?

Answer (score 6):

The id shouldn't determine position or ordering.  It should be an immutable identifier.

If you need to represent order in a database you need to create another orderNumber column.  A couple options are (1) either have values that span a range or (2) have a pointer to next (like a linked list).

**For ranges:** Spanning a range helps you avoid rewriting the orderNumber column for all items after the insert point.  For example, in the range, insert first gets 1, insert 2nd gets max range, insert 3rd between first and second gets mid-range number - if you reposition you have to assign mid-points of the items it's between.  One downside is if the list gets enough churn (minimized by a large span) you may have to rebalance the ranges.  The pro of this solution is you can get the ordered list just by ordering by this column in the sql statement.

**For linked list:**  If the database has a next column that points to the id that's after it in order, you need to update a couple rows to insert something.  Upside is it's simple.  Downside is you can't order in the sql statement - you're relying on the code getting the list to sort it.

One other variation is you could pull the ordered list data out of that table altogether.  For example, you could have an ordered list table that has listid, itemid, orderedNumber.  That allows you to have one or multiple logical ordered lists of the items in that table it references.

Some other references:

[How to store ordered items which often change position in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399253/how-to-store-ordered-items-which-often-change-position-in-db)

[Best way to save a ordered List to the Database while keeping the ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330482/best-way-to-save-a-ordered-list-to-the-database-while-keeping-the-ordering)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/how-to-design-a-database-for-storing-a-sorted-list